# Cannot create STREAM from file or string

Tags: c#, winforms, stream, amazon-mws

I am trying to create a stream from a file or a string but I am getting the below error.

```
ReadTimeout = 'stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
WriteTimeout = 'stream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

I found a sample code to create a stream. It seems fine but it gives the error above

By the way, I am trying to send data to Amazon MWS Feed Api. Here is my full code below.

```
using (Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString("D:\\feed.xml"))
{
      SubmitFeedRequest request = new SubmitFeedRequest();
      request.Merchant = merchantId;
      request.MarketplaceIdList = new IdList();
      request.MarketplaceIdList.Id = new List<string>(new string[] { marketplaceId });
      request.FeedContent = s;
      request.ContentMD5 = MarketplaceWebServiceClient.CalculateContentMD5(request.FeedContent);
      //request.FeedContent.Position = 0;

      request.FeedType = "_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_";

      SubmitFeedSample.InvokeSubmitFeed(service, request);
  }


 public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
 {
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
     StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
     writer.Write(s);
     writer.Flush();
     stream.Position = 0;
     return stream;
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

It gives the error seen in the image below:

[image]

Comment: what is `s`?  Is it a filename or the actual stream content itself?

Comment: also, your code works on my machine.  is there any other code that I'm not seeing?  When an exception is thrown, it might create a break point for you.  do you know what line it's failing on?

Comment: I am passing the string(content) to the function above

Comment: I am passing the string(content) to the function above....doesn't answer the question.   is "Content"  a valid file?   what is the value of "content"

Comment: I tried to pass "D:\\feed.xml" to the function. It didnt work. Then I tried to pass "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> ......."  It didnt work either

Comment: @ayilmaz Is your codebase small enough to edit your question and post you entire code?

Comment: @SamIam, I added my code into my question

Comment: @ayilmaz does this question, by chance, have something to do with [Amazon Marketplace Web Services](https://developer.amazonservices.com/)?

Comment: umm, you never keep the result of the call to `GenerateStreamFromString` in your updated code.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that I am doing this for Amazon MWS

Comment: @alimaz on what line to you **actually** get that exception.  Your stream generating function that you wrote should not throw an exception.

Comment: Well, I doesnt give exception but I saw the error on DEBUG. It doesnt stop the program. I thought that because of the error, my program didnt work as expected

Comment: The error that you show is not an error, is the debugger trying to access to properties that throws an exception. You can work with this MemoryStream without problems.

Comment: @ayilmaz  Sometimes, the Debugger is unable to access certain properties at runtime.  That doesn't always mean that there's an error.  IF you run the code             `using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString("abc"))
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }`, and make a breakpoint at the end, the value of `text` will have the content of your stream.  As you can see, it will be the string that you fed into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MemoryStream class does not support TimeOut. 
You can check it checking the property CanTimeout.

```
bool canTimeout = stream.CanTimeout;
```

If CanTimeout is false calling to properties ReadTimeout or WriteTimeout is not allowed and throws an exception.

ReadTimeout can be used for NetworkStream for example.

Comment: CanTimeout returns false. So, how am I supposed to create a stream? ı dont get it

Comment: You have a functional MemoryStream, but you cannot call to ReadTimeout or WriteTimeout. It's not a good OOP style implementation from Microsoft...

Comment: I am not calling ReadTimeout/WriteTimeout. Who is calling it?

Comment: I don't understand, are you getting an exception when executes this method without calling to timeout properties?

Comment: By the way, I am the one who downvoted, and I did so because your question does very little toward answering the OP's actual question

Comment: I know that you might be thinking that the OP's question is unanswerable given the limited amount of information that's provided.  But for an unanswerable question, It's only natural that the "answers" posted will be insufficient.